# Pig Script STRSPLIT

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, latin

My column has first name and last name separated by SPACE. I want to use pig function to split into 2 different columns. I think of STRSPLIT function but I don't know how to use it.
Could anyone help me on this simple question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, sample code below
here what i am doing is
1.Reading each line as single column
2.Apply the STRSPLIT function using space as delimiter
3.Store the firstname and lastname into two different columns

```
input.txt
Pearson Charles
James  Michael
Smith Linda

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\s+',2)) AS (firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE firstname,lastname;
DUMP C;

Output:
(Pearson,Charles)
(James,Michael)
(Smith,Linda)
```

Check more info from this link
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#strsplit

Comment: Sivasakthi Jayaraman one question in my legacy code I see STRSPLIT(line,'_',1), it always returns same as input line. Not sure why this is being used..Any thoughts on this